# Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset | data trimmed in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, symfony

I'm working with symfony 2, I have an entity that contains an array, in MySQL database the array column was generated as a `longtext utf8_unicode_ci` column with the comment `DC2Type:array`.

When querying the database for the entity I get the error :

> Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 894 of 902 bytes
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

I searched for the same error on SO, but I found that the problem comes from the column in the database, it appears that the array wasn't entirely stored and was trimmed although the `longText` type of columns can store up to 4 Gigabytes of data.

Is there any way to prevent the array from being trimmed ?
And thanx for advance.

Comment: my be the reason will that some quotes are present there at the time of saving and that's why full data is not stored. And at the time of fetching it creates problem.

Comment: Do you tried clear the cache completely?

Comment: @Anant , no there're no quotes in my data

Comment: @Yonel, yeah I regularly clear the cache, the issue is still there

Comment: this happened just after restore a backup database ? on persist this entity ? when exactly was started the error?

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to those who tried to help but I found the problem's origin, I had a within my array a random generated token :

```
$commande['token'] = random_bytes(10);
```

When I tried the `var_dump` on it, it was a weird random string with special caracters so I searched the symfony2 docs and found this :

> The random_bytes() function returns a binary string which may contain the \0 character. This can cause trouble in several common scenarios, such as storing this value in a database or including it as part of the URL. The solution is to encode or hash the value returned by random_bytes() (to do that, you can use a simple base64_encode() PHP function).

so I added the `base64_encode()` function and it worked.

```
$commande['token'] = base64_encode(random_bytes(10));
```

Comment: php doesn't care about nulls. But if you're stuffing those random bytes into a serialized string directly, those random bytes CAN contain serialization metachars, like quotes or escapes. e.g. you're suffering from the serialization equivalent of an sql injection attack.

Comment: base64 doesn't contain serialization metachars, so it'll work, but if you are storing what amounts to binary data, you shouldn't be using a text-type field. those are subject to charset translation rules. your random bytes can either be an unintended valid multi-byte unicode sequence, or a completely invalid one. b64 papers over that by translating any arbitrary binary data into plain text.